# Grafico de Admin LTE2 no funciona en el hosting

Tags: php, laravel-8, charts, adminlte

Estoy trabajando en Laravel 8, utilizando la plantilla ADMIN LTE2, usé el gráfico de barras, y los datos los tomo de un calculo de promedios de los campos de una tabla. y tengo las rutas apuntando al hosting tanto en la plantilla con en el archivo, de forma local trabaja perfecto, muestra los datos y el gráfico, pero cuando lo uso en el hosting solo muestra los datos y saca el grafico en blanco. agradezco si alguien puede ayudarme.

adjunto el codigo,

```
<script>
```

$(function () {

```
/*
 * BAR CHART2
 * ---------
 */

 var bar_data = {
  data : [['Día Abierto', {{ $PRB26 }}], ['Sostenimiento', {{ $PRB09 }}], ['Día Problema', {{ $PRB38 }}]],
  // data : [['Día Abierto', {{ number_format($PRB26, 0) }}], ['Sostenimiento', {{ number_format($PRB09, 0) }}], ['Día Problema', {{ number_format($PRB38, 0) }}]],
  color: '#3c8dbc'
}
$.plot('#bar-chart2', [bar_data], {
  grid  : {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#f3f3f3',
    tickColor  : '#f3f3f3'
  },
  series: {
    bars: {
      show    : true,
      barWidth: 0.5,
      align   : 'center'
    }
  },
  xaxis : {
    mode      : 'categories',
    tickLength: 0
  }
})
/* END BAR CHART */
```

})

/*

- Custom Label formatter
- ---

*/
function labelFormatter(label, series) {
return ''
+ label
+ '
'
+ Math.round(series.percent) + '%'
}

Comment: Te falta la etiqueta de abrir el script ( <script> ), no se si eso te solucionará el problema, pero empieza probando x ahí...

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, el script que me comentas si lo tenia, pero no pude copiar el codigo completo, no me lo permite, parece que por largo, copio solo el fragmento de los datos del gráfico,